# C program that converts file contents

Tags: c

I want to write a program that converts integer to another char and print them. I expect to work but It didn't work anyway even if I want to print same integer without converting. 
My code is here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    FILE *fp;
    int a;
    fp=fopen("deneme.txt", "r");
    while(feof(fp)) {
        fscanf(fp,"%d",&a);
        switch(a) {
        case 0:
            printf(" ");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("-");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("_");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("|");
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("/");
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("\\");
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("O");
            break;  
        default:
            break;      
        }   
    }   
}
```

My txt is that:
[image]

Comment: Change `scanf`'s `%d` to `%c` and the `case`s to `'0'` from `0`, `'1'` from `1` etc. Changing `a` type to `char` also not bad idea then. The problem now is that you seem to assume that `scanf` will read only 1 digit at a time but it is just not with `%d`.

Comment: Also a good idea to learn how to debug effectively. The best way to do that is to use a debugger. Step through the code line by line and you'll be able to see what it is doing. Can also examine the variables as you step the code.